# Sudden Bad Request - Invalid Verb on during debugging Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, iis

During development I suddenly started to receive following error message

```
Bad Request - Invalid Verb

HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.
```

The website under development was run on ISSExpress via Visual Studio. It stopped working out of the blue, without any changes in the configuration.

I'm using: ASP MVC, C#

What can be the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was caused by... an invalid cookie.

**The solution was to remove all cookies.**

(I accidentally checked the page on other browser and it worked there.)

Comment: Thanks for this solution and it worked for me as well, but do we know WHY it fixes the issue? I'm hesitant to recommend this solution to my team until I can explain why that worked. Thanks again

Comment: @nurseymybush I may be connected with: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36795259/257470