# Too many cookies OpenIdConnect.nonce cause error page "Bad Request - Request Too Long"

Tags: asp.net, cookies, oauth, owin

I'm using OWIN / OAuth with OpenId Connect authentication (`Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect`) in a C# ASP MVC web app. The SSO login with Microsoft account basically works, but from time to time I'm getting an error page on the browser that says `Bad Request - Request Too Long`.

I found out that this error is caused by too many cookies. Deleting cookies helps for some time, but after a while the problem comes back.

The cookies that cause the problem are set from OpenId framework, so there are dozens of cookies with names like `OpenIdConnect.nonce.9oEtF53WxOi2uAw.......`.

This is not SPA application, but some parts are refreshed periodically with ajax calls.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It turned out that the root cause was the Ajax call.

**The problematic flow was**

1) OAuth cookie got expired after some time

2) Expiration normally causes redirection the page to `login.microsoft.com` to refresh the cookie. In this step OAuth framework **adds new** `nonce` cookie to the response (every time)!

3) But Ajax doesn't handle redirections outside of the domain (cross-domain to `login.microsoft.com`). But the cookie was already appended to the page.

4) Next periodical Ajax call repeated the flow causing rapid increase of 'nonce' cookies.

**Solution**

I had to extend the "OWIN OpenId" framework setup code to handle Ajax calls differently - to prevent redirection and stop sending cookies.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx => 
                {
                    bool isAjaxRequest = (ctx.Request.Headers != null && ctx.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest");

                    if (isAjaxRequest)
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie");
                        ctx.State = NotificationResultState.HandledResponse;
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

The Ajax caller had to be adjusted too to detect `401` code and perform full page refresh (which caused a quick redirect to Microsoft authority).

Comment: Thank you. I was having a similar issue and this helped resolve it.

Comment: This also appeared to solve my problem once I cleared chrome cookies. Ironically MS's brave new browser Edge.... has just as many inconsistencies and performance issues as IE, so I'm back to using chrome for now.

Comment: Solved my problem too. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

For me the solution was to enforce the creation of an ASP.NET session.

**Steps to reproduce**:

- Delete ASP.NET_SessionId cookie and idsrv cookie on a protected page
  of your webapp
- Reload page
- Redirect to OIDC authentication store and authenticate
- Redirect back to webapp => validation of the authentication fails,
  because no asp.net session is available
- Endless redirects until 'Request too long...' error happens

**Solution**:
Enforce session creation by adding

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

to global.asax.cs.

Answer (score 1):

OWIN and MVC may be deleting each other's cookies as described by the [AspNetKatana github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/System.Web-response-cookie-integration-issues).

- As a workaround that page suggests to explicitly use `SystemWebCookieManager` or `SystemWebChunkingCookieManager` (Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 3.1.0).
- There is also the [Kentor Owin Cookie Saver](https://github.com/Sustainsys/owin-cookie-saver) as a workaround.
- However, I would first try upgrading to [Owin 4.1.0](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/Roadmap#410-release-november-2019) (released november 2019), as this seems to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the order in which I was configuring the application inside `Startup.cs`.

Reminder to self - always configure authentication first!

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = _clientId,
                ClientSecret = _clientSecret,
                Authority = _authority,
                RedirectUri = _redirectUri
            });

        // configure the rest of the application...
    }
```