# Understanding a 400 bad request only on chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-chrome, iis-7

I get this error with my .Net app but it only occurs on chrome on 2 pages on my site and only on my network.

[image: Bad Request]

What does the notes in the image mean? If I hit refresh it works fine. How do I figure out what the headers are and if it's a network or security thing?

Comment: i guess it must b network security thing if its having such issue in only in your network

Comment: May be related to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654199/sudden-bad-request-invalid-verb-on-during-debugging-visual-studio

Comment: clear cookie and session data still happens

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cookies. This must be caused by an invalid cookie. Had the same issue and clearing the cookies worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Followings can be possible options to look at:

- As you getting issues in Chrome, clear cache/cookies
- Error 400: The Web server thinks that the data stream sent by the client (e.g.
  your Web browser) was 'malformed' i.e. did
  not respect the HTTP protocol completely. So the Web server was
  unable to understand the request and process it.
- It indicates that the two systems (our robot and the Web server)
  fundamentally disagree on the syntax of HTTP data streams. Mare sure you are not calling HTTPS from HTTP?

Hope this helps!